# Get record by value or get last record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to get a record if there is a value otherwise grab the last record. I do currently have a solution using an `if` statement like the one below:

```
if (!empty($version)) {
    $sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `versioning` WHERE `id`='$itemID' AND `version`='$version' ORDER BY `version` DESC LIMIT 1";
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `versioning` WHERE `id`='$itemID' ORDER BY `version` DESC LIMIT 1";
}
```

**My question is:** Is there was a way to do this in a single `sql` statement and if there is, what would be the pros or cons of doing it in a single statement?

**To help clarify**
I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use one `sql` statement instead of an `if` statement to get either the specified `version` or if `version` is empty I would like to get the last `version` from the `versioning` table.

Comment: *if version is empty* .. you mean the variable '$version'?

Comment: I do mean the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by one sql like the following

```
$version = (!empty($version))?$version:'%%';
$sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `versioning` WHERE `id`='$itemID' AND `version` LIKE '$version' ORDER BY `version` DESC LIMIT 1";
```

by using one line, it can be useful if you like to change the conditions in the sql or add more fields or add another join statements
,,, all this you do not have to modify two sql lines

Comment: You know I use that short if statement all the time. I never even thought to use it for this solution. This is a wonderful answer. The one reason I was trying to get it down to one SQL like was I have had to keep going back and editing it and I would forget to edit the second one.

Comment: I actually just tried it by making the line read `$sql = "SELECT `version` FROM `snippet_version` WHERE `snippet_id`='$snippetID' AND `version` like '%$version%' ORDER BY `version` DESC LIMIT 1";` and this also works if `$version` is empty. It remove the need for the short had `if` statement.

Comment: great hhhhh i did not expect this

Answer (score 0):

May not be using ANSI SQL statement but you can use a stored procedure though for passing the parameter and call that procedure instead in your app code like

```
create procedure usp_version (version varchar(10))
as
begin
if version is not null then
SELECT `version` FROM `versioning` 
WHERE `id`='$itemID' 
AND `version`='$version' 
ORDER BY `version` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
else
SELECT `version` 
FROM `versioning` 
WHERE `id`='$itemID' 
ORDER BY `version` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
end if;
end
```